# How to calculate the Total Time taken for a particular Transaction in a Thread Group?

Tags: jmeter

I have a following Thread Group Settings:

- Threads: 10
- Ramp-Up: 10
- Loop Count: 1

And this is how my Thread Group is constructed:

```
Thread Group
Transaction Controller
   Login
   View Customers
   Customer Detail Page
   Edit & Update
   Logout
```

I want to know the Total Time taken by the **Edit & Update** Transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the test plan.

From Login to Logout can not be a single transaction - does not look correct.

As you are interested only in measuring `Edit and Update` - the test plan can be as given below.

```
Thread Group
   Login
   View Customers
   Customer Detail Page
   Transaction Controller
      Edit & Update
   Logout
```

Enable `Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample` in the Transaction Controller.

You will get the total time taken for Edit and Update.

---

**Update:**

When you say total time taken - you mean total time of all the Edit & Update. Lets say - in your case as you have 10 threads - so you will have 10 Edit and Update. You want the total time of all the 10 Edit and update?? If yes, then there is no listener for this purpose. Because mostly no one would be interested in that metric!! We would need max, min, avg, median, 90% line from those 10 samples!!

If that is what you want, you can simply calculate that yourself `Total = Avg * No of samples`

Comment: Hi Vinoth, thanks for pointing out my mistake. It is basically mistake happened during raising the question. I do have Transaction Controller in each and every transactions. 

Anyway, thanks for the answer but which Listener is to be used? 

I do not find any Listener which gives the Total Time Taken for a particular Transaction. It displays Average Response Time, and other metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.